# Windows 10 upgrade puzzle

Tags: windows-10

A few days ago, I upgraded from Windows 7 to 10 1903 with a free download from https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows10. Installed it, and everything worked fine... except that...

Even though a single admin user was created by Windows called User...

...the initial "page" or "window" for logging in to Windows (right after you turn on the computer) always displayed a duplicate of the User button. Both buttons led to a password window, which led to opening Windows.

But I didn't want two admin Users, nor two buttons for one User. I searched for a way to make it stop displaying the dupe, and tried everything I could, including opening netplwiz and checking and unchecking the "...require password..." box and restarting, etc.

Nothing showed that two User admin accounts had been created, so that I could delete one. Everything indicated that there was only one admin account.

But I was still not comfortable with having two buttons for the admin account User. And nothing I tried got rid of the duplicate button. So...

...I tried one other recommendation for fixing this problem, which was to use a RETAIL license key. I assumed this meant one I paid $199 for, rather than the free one I got by downloading from the page linked-to above. So I paid for a new license key. Two actually, because I'm trying to securely upgrade two computers. So I got two license keys for $399.

The file name of what I was able to download with the paid link was identical to the free one, namely MediaCreationTool1903.exe.

I put the new download on a USB stick, since the instructions said to either do that or use a CD/DVD. Then I went through the several-hours-long download and installation process from the USB stick.

At the very end of the hours-long process, including the step of downloading updates, a window opened that said something like, "This version of Windows can't be installed ... because of your hardware ... When an update is ready it will be automatically installed ... Try removing all the plugged-in things and trying installing again"

Hmmm... I had already installed a download of the Windows 10 1903 .exe that was available for free from Microsoft's site and cost nothing. I was now trying to solve the problem of a duplicate User button displaying on the initial page.

Also strange that the workaround says to remove all plugged-in things and try installing again, since I thought you have to install from a removable medium, i.e. USB or CD/DVD.

I read discussions of this problem, and something or someone suggested copying the .exe from the USB stick to my local drive and installing from there. Which seemed weird; instructions all say to use removable media -- either USB or CD/DVD.

But I did that anyway (copied the file from USB to local drive and tried installing from there).

Again, at the end of this very long process, I got the same message as before, that says this version of Windows can't be installed on my computer. It's not a very old computer, by the way.

I suppose I can continue using this computer with the two admin User buttons, especially since it does appear that there is in reality only one admin account.

Can I get a refund from Microsoft for these two keys that I didn't need to buy? I think the free one is identical to the one I paid for. I know it was possible to install the free one. I just feared that perhaps the paid-for one would be more sure to be reliable, and not do things like display two buttons for one User admin account.

If this isn't the best place to post this question, can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

According to this:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/10558/microsoft-store-returning-items-bought-for-exchange-refund

I cannot get a refund.

I haven't even used the one of the two purchased license keys.

I did use the other one. I didn't need either of them.

What an expensive mistake.